# Sort Java object and find relative position based on a attribute

Tags: java, algorithm, logic

I have an interesting problem

Here is the  object structure

```
public class Testdata {
    //Which is a consecutive running number i.e 1,2,3..etc
    private int sequence;

    //classified based on this again any random numbers
    private int window; 

    //need to calculate
    private int windowposition; 

}
```

Now based on the sequence and window , i would need to derive windowposition in relation to the window

**Test Data**
    So for testdata   sequence/window

```
        1 / 2
        2 / 3
        3 / 2
        4 / 3
        5 / 3
```

**Expected Output**

```
    sequence/window :   window position would be (in the same order)

    1 / 2       :   1

    2 / 3       :   1

    3 / 2       :   2

    4 / 3       :   2

    5 / 3       :   3
```

Update:

yes indeed , I have already implemented comparable and sorted the list to below order

```
1 / 2
3 / 2
2 / 3        
4 / 3
5 / 3
```

Now how do I calculate the `windowposition` of each element in relation to its window

Comment: do you need windowsposition = sumOfPreviousWindowById(window) + 1?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @ngmiceli    read the question thotoughly, you will notice , in case if you still havent "Now based on the sequence and window , i would need to derive windowposition in relation to the window "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably make sense to implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). That allows your objects to be sorted. You would implement `compareTo(T)` like so:

```
int compareTo(Testdata o) {
  return ((Integer)this.sequence).compareTo(o.sequence);
}
```

That way your objects can be sorted by sequence.

Now collect all the objects with `window` 1 into a `List`, objects with `window` 2 into another list etc.

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Testdata>> map = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Testdata>>();

// Add all the objects like this
while (...) { // While there are more objects
  Testdata td = ... // Get next object

  List<TestData> list = map.get(td.window);
  if (list == null) {
    list = new ArrayList<Testdata>();
    map.put(td.window, list);
  }

  list.add(td.sequence);
}
```

Sort all of the lists using [Collections.sort(List)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29):

```
for (ArrayList<TestData> list : map) {
  Collections.sort(list);
}
```

You then have one list for each window, accessible via `map.get(window)`. Each of these lists has the object with the lowest `sequence` as its first object, second lowest as second object etc. -> the window position is the index of the object + 1.

**EDIT:**

If your objects are already sorted by window and sequence (into a single list), you can do something like this to assign the window positions:

```
int window = 1;
int wp = 0;
for (Testdata td : list) {
  if (td.window > window) {
    wp = 1;
    window = td.window;
  } else {
    wp++;
  }

  td.windowposition = wp;
}
```

Comment: This will not give you the desired output. You need to find the window position based on the sequence. So compareTo should be based on "sequence".

Comment: @Deepa actually the compareTo should be based on both sequence and windowposition

Answer (score 0):

So, the *windowposition* is just another sequence. I would put in a `Map<Integer,Integer>` the last *windowposition* of every window.
You don't necessarily have to sort your objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
So its basically window's no. of occurrence in the array of objects.
Seq/Window:Position
1 / 2 : 1    => Window 2 , 1st position (1st occurrence of Window 2)
2 / 3 : 1    => Window 3 , 1st position (1st occurrence of Window 3)
3 / 2 : 2    => Window 2 , 2nd position (since Window 2 has already positioned in sequence 1)
4 / 3 : 2    => Window 3 , 2nd position (since Window 3 has already positioned in sequence 2)
5 / 3 : 3    => Window 3 , 3rd position (since Window 3 has already positioned in sequence 2 and 4)

Is that right?

List<Window> windows = new ArrayList<Window>();
        windows.add(new Window(2, 3));
        windows.add(new Window(1, 2));
        windows.add(new Window(3, 2));
        windows.add(new Window(4, 3));
        windows.add(new Window(5, 3));

        Collections.sort(windows);

HashMap<Integer, Integer> wpMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
     Integer wpos;
        for (Window w : windows) {
            wpos = wpMap.get(w.window);
            if ( wpos == null ) { 
                wpos = 1;
            } else { 
                wpos++;
            }
            w.setWindowPosition(wpos);
            wpMap.put(w.window, wpos);
        }
    for (Window w : windows) {
        System.out.println(w.sequence+"/"+w.window+":"+w.windowposition);
    }
```

Comment: yes indeed , i have already implemented comparable and sorted the list to below order   
        1 / 2
        3 / 2
        2 / 3        
        4 / 3
        5 / 3


Now how do i calculate the windowposition of each element in relation to its window

Comment: Check the updated comment. This will be after sorting the list based on sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
windowposition = sequence - window < 0 ? 1 : sequence - window + 1;
```